# Undefined variable in function php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following php code below, it keeps throwing out a undefined variable `$checked` once the plugin is activated.

How do I use function in function correctly?

[image: meta.php]

Comment: The $checked variable is not defined in function "gb_sidebar...", it is only available in function "sanitize_checked". Both function are called in a different way. You could (bad design!) expose the value of $checked into a global variable, if you can ensure, the "sanitize_checked" is ALWAYS called before "gb_sidebar...". Than you access this global variable in "gb_sidebar...".
You should read something about scopes of variables in script/programming languages, to understand, what I mean, if it was to abstract.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: The screenshot shows that the global variable comes before the gb_sidebar function and is then called in gb_sidebar.
Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: $checked is not defined in that gb_... function

Answer (score -1):

write this :

```
function sanitize_check($check = null)
```

insted:

```
function sanitize_check($check)
```

Comment: I have the same problem as in the beginning

Comment: @paflik in second function you dont set $checked

Comment: If I don't set $checked in the second function - I have fatal error "Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError, Too few arguments to function sanitize_check(), 0 passed" when I activate plugin.

Comment: @paflik yes , you should define it. or pass to function